# How can I get Apache to "not match" my given AliasMatch?

Tags: regex, apache, alias

Here's my current regex:

```
 AliasMatch ^/?=(test)$ /srv/test.com/python/load.wsgi
```

Basically, I'm trying to send everything but the URL `/test` to my `load.wsgi` file so that everything else will be handled by PHP.

This regex is failing. I've also tried:

```
AliasMatch !^/test$
```

But that also failed. How can I perform the 'not match'?

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite is more flexible and allows any number of RewriteCond statements to modify the conditions under which a RewiteRule will be applied, such as

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test 
RewriteRule . /srv/test.com/python/load.wsgi
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^/test'` when I try this method

Comment: Sorry, was being to to quick. You have to tell the Cond line what to match against. Corrected now above.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, negative lookahead is your friend:

`^(?!/?test$).*$`

Answer (score -1):

```
^[^(\/test)]
```

anything that doesn't start with /test

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope. `^[^(\/test)]` is a character class which says: _match any one character which is not a '(' or 't' or 'e' or 's' or ')'_